# Odd blank space at the top of horizontal UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a blank space that I can't locate the cause of at the top of a UICollectionView.

I have disabled the header in the storyboard so I don't believe it to be that.

Here is a picture:

[image]

The code for the CollectionView

```
- (void)setupCollectionView
{
  [self.scoreCollectionView setDataSource:self];
  [self.scoreCollectionView setDelegate:self];
  [self.scoreCollectionView registerClass:[AAScoreCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  AAScoreCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (_selectedIndexPath) {
    [cell showSelection:[indexPath isEqual:_selectedIndexPath]];
  }

  return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  AAScoreCell *cell = (AAScoreCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell showSelection:![indexPath isEqual:_selectedIndexPath]];
  _selectedIndexPath = [indexPath isEqual:_selectedIndexPath] ? nil : indexPath;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  AAScoreCell *cell = (AAScoreCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell showSelection:NO];
  _selectedIndexPath = nil;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return CGSizeMake(self.scoreCollectionView.frame.size.height-50, self.scoreCollectionView.frame.size.height-50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not going to pretend I understand why but:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

solved the issue for me